# Bookdown: Removing social media links?

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, gitbook, bookdown

I am using bookdown to write a report for a client. They like it, I like it but I don't want to have the social media links in the top right of the compiled html. Other than editing the html after build, is there any way to stop them appearing during building the report?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set `sharing` to `null` in `config` in the `gitbook` output format: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/html.html

```
bookdown::gitbook:
  config:
    sharing: null
```